# Liquid not showing after the domain is resized 2.91.0

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

Every time I try to create smoke or liquid simulation the smoke or liquid dissapears permanently after I resize the domain.
I have tried:
Applying scale to inflow, domain, inflow and domain;
Using replay, replay (resumable), modular, modular (resumable), all;
Starting the same thing over in new .blend multiple times;
Using quick smoke/quick liquid (this shows the liquid/smoke but it dissapears the second I resize the domain)
Here are an example settings and scene where the liquid isn't showing:

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

I can only create simulations if I use quick smoke/liquid effects and don't resize the domain at all witch is very limiting since the domain that gets created automatically is usually pretty tightly wrapped around the inflow objects.

Comment: Make sure to increase your resolution(currently set to 32)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without blend ... but it seems to me your inflow object is smaller than one domain division ... means there is nothing to generate.

Enlarge Inflow object or increase domain resolution ... or you just didn't play whole anim sequence?